# How to get user data from the access token without JWT

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, access-token, azure-ad-graph-api

I am getting Access token from the Azure AD Login. 
But i don't want to use JWT dll for extract data from the Access Token.
So i need a alternative solution for this.
This is my Sample code  in JWT

```
 var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            JwtSecurityToken tokenS = handler.ReadToken(data.AccessToken) as JwtSecurityToken;
            var claims = tokenS.Claims;
            var username = claims.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Type == "email").Value;
```

used dlls: using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt; 
I don't want this dll for extract data. I need another solution without using dll.

Answer (score 1):

I will not ask why you dont want to use the library you have for the exact purpose its intended for. Anyway a JWT is just  3 base 64 encoded strings concatenated with '.', (assuming its signed but not encrypted)

So:

```
var split = jwt.Split('.')
var token = Convert.FromBase64String(split([1]))
```

the middle bit is the token in json, use newtonsoft to read it

Comment: The problem with just decoding the base 64 encoded string, is that you don't verify the signature. So you have no guarantee that the JWT token originates from the source you are expecting.

Comment: indeed, but my reading of the question is that the AZAD infrastructure has already authenticated the JWT.